# python sending to 1 person and 2 bcc

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I have a problem whit sending a mail. from emails I get from a program but when I send it the user. they can see the bcc emails address. I have searched for an answer but most are for multi address and not cc or bcc address

so I need a solution that will send bcc but there hidden from the user and bcc receives them

```
def mail(self, email_user, to, subject, text, attach,attach2, email_pwd, smtp, port):
    msg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = to # @newuser.be
    msg['Bcc'] = "tt@boss.be"
    msg['cc'] = "zz@boss.be"
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    part = MIMEText(text,'html')
    #msg.attach(email.MIMEText.MIMEText(text))
    msg.attach(part)
    if attach:
        part = email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
        email.Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
        msg.attach(part)
    if attach2:
        part = email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(attach2, 'rb').read())
        email.Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach2))
        msg.attach(part)
    if( port != "" ):
        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(smtp, port)
    else:
        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(smtp)

    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(email_user, email_pwd)
    mailServer.sendmail(email_user, to, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
msg['To'] = to # @newuser.be
msg['Bcc'] = "tt@boss.be"
msg['cc'] = "zz@boss.be"
```

with:

```
msg['To'] = to 
msg['cc'] = "zz@boss.be"
to = [ to, "zz@boss.be", "tt@boss.be" ]
```